# Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page for Angular pages

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor

I am getting below error when loading the very first page (base url in the conf.ts)

Protractor Version 4.0.9

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/test"
        at C:\Users\A133928\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:273:23
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\A133928\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\A133928\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\A133928\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\A133928\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27)
        at C:\Users\A133928\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

I have gone through similar kind of question in here as well.

[Resolution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634648/getting-error-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page)

But the issue is, I tried [Resolution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059943/running-into-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-with-basic) and apply some wait as mentioned below. Still even after page fully loaded I get the same said error.

**Code:**

```
beforeEach(() => {


        loginPage.getPage();
        browser.sleep(5000);

        loginPage.userLogin(data.users[1].email, data.users[1].password );
        browser.waitForAngular();
```

**Conf.ts**

```
export let config: Config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    rootElement: '.myApp',
    // capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome'},
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['--start-maximized']
            },

        }],

    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    seleniumPort: null,
    seleniumArgs: [],
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but `rootElement` in your config needs a CSS selector (default is <body>).  Is your `ng-app` attribute on an element with a class of `.myApp`?

Comment: try `rootElement: "[ng-app]"`

Comment: @Gunderson I tried `.myApp` because it was there in the answer in the said question. Even without dot, it doesn't work.

Comment: @TehBeardedOne I get same error with that as well. i.e. `rootElement: "[ng-app]" `

Comment: @Gunderson Sorry, In my page `<div ng-app="myApp" style="height: 100%;" ui-view class = "ng-scope" `. Under the body tag `role="main" id="main" autoscroll `

Comment: As a solution I have changed the application code by moving `ng-app="myApp" ` from `<div..` to `<body...` then it worked.